How to limit input audio signal to maximum 2.1Vrms
I am making a car stereo which has two inputs: A 3.5mm connector and bluetooth. The bluetooth signal is converted to analog using PCM5102 which output is 2.1Vrms.
The purpose of the summing amplifier is to switch to either of the audio inputs when the other one is not present (one of them is always 0).
So, my question is how can i make the signal from the aux input (J1) be limited to maximum 2.1Vrms, no matter its input voltage.

You don't want to enforce a hard limit of 2.1Vrms, otherwise you'll get distortion and it will sound bad... you might want to look into compression, but this is more complex and you'll want to be able to tweak the attack/release time, otherwise it'll sound bad... what's wrong with just adjusting the source volume to suit, and not being too scientific about it?

@Attie I don't disagree with you, but maybe getting audible clipping artifacts is what the user needs to hear to realize they have to turn the volume on their source waaaaaaay down?

sweg, do you really mean to have a summing amplifier, although you don't want to sum two sources, but to switch between them?

@MarcusMüller agreed! (on both counts) "turning it down due to clipping" is how I've always dealt with such things in the past... in which case, no circuitry is required(?)

If those opamps are powered with +/- 3.3V, then they'll pretty much do the limiting for you, since 2.1V RMS is 5.9V peak-to-peak

They are powered with +- 5V, the problem is that i dont know the voltage of the phone aux output, and from what i found it varies, i want to make sure that when i switch from bluetooth to aux in i wont have to turn the volume up

my logic is that i dont want to use analog switches, and in the summing amplifier i always sum a signal with zero, also i dont have formal electronics education and kind of still learn things by myself, this is my 12th grade diploma project

and i want to limit the signal without clipping and distortion to max 2.1Vrms

@sweg - please edit the question with this additional information. As above, in this case you're looking for a "dynamic range compression" (or the source's volume control).

thank you, is this simple to implement?

"and i want to limit the signal without clipping and distortion to max 2.1Vrms" um, limiting is distorting. "I want to trim my hedge to a height of 2.1m, but I don't want to affect my hedge" would be analogous to this. Can you explain exactly what should happen when a signal with an RMS larger than 2.1 V is applied? Maybe for a simple signal, like a sine wave?


how can i make the signal from the aux input (J1) be limited to
maximum 2.1Vrms, no matter its input voltage.

You could use a compressor circuit to help you achieve your goal. Start with a voltage controlled amplifier like the THAT218X and measure the input signal with an RMS level detector like the THAT2252. This design note has a schematic you could use: -

Reality check on your requirements

If the input level is very low i.e. rudimentary noise then the output will not be 2.1 volts RMS.
Furthermore, I suspect that it's more likely that a peak signal limiting circuit is more useful to you but, this can be achieved by replacing the RMS level detector with a peak level detector.


thank you, i will look into this peak limiting circuit

@sweg give it a couple of days then, if we are done here, please take note of this: What should I do when someone answers my question. If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

You can't easily limit RMS voltage, because RMS voltage is related to its average value. Average voltage will be different for a square wave, than for a sinusoid, for example. To know how much attenuation will be necessary in order to avoid exceeding some "ceiling" average, you would need to look into the future, to see the waveform as it will be in the next few milliseconds, calculate its average, and then set the appropriate attenuation level in the present.
That's obviously absurd, but other tricks do exist. You can do the averaging for a recent (in the past) interval of signal input, and then begin attenuation, just a little late. That won't prevent sudden bursts of excessive power getting through, but such a system can react quickly enough to ensure that it doesn't last for more than a few milliseconds. That's the approach suggested by Andy aka.
You absolutely can limit instantaneous voltage, because that is known right now, and can be "clamped" to some maximum, right now. The simplest approach is probably a voltage follower using a rail-to-rail output op-amp:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The op-amp cannot output voltages beyond its own supplies, so output voltage here can never fall outside the range −2.1V to +2.1V, which is 4.2V peak-to-peak. The hardest part about this design is finding/building a dual ±2.1V power supply. That will be significantly more complex than the actual amplifier.
Clamping like this causes clipping, if the input signal is too large, which is of course heavy distortion. I suspect that this will be a deal breaker, so I'm not inclined to make any effort here to elaborate on this approach.
